# How to initialize a list of a generic class

Tags: c#, .net, list, generics

I have a generic class

```
public class MetadataDifference<T>
{
    public T NewMetadata { get; private set; }
    public T OldMetadata { get; private set; }
    // Other useful properties

    public MetadataDifference(T newMetadata, T oldMetadata)
    {
        NewMetadata = newMetadata;
        OldMetadata = oldMetadata;
    }
}
```

I have wrapper class which has a list of MetadataDifference<> as a property.

This doesn't work:

> The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found

Code:

```
public class DifferencesResult
{
    public IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<T>> MetadataChanges { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

How can I initialize a list of a generic object? Is it possible?

Comment: Since `DifferencesResult` is not generic it should know what type `T` is, for example: `IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<string>> MetadataChanges { get; set; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define an interface that doesn't have any generic types which `MetadataDifference` implements to provide untyped access to the underlying object:

```
public interface IMetadataDifference
{
    object NewMetadata { get; }
    object OldMetadata { get; }
}

public interface IMetadataDifference<out T> : IMetadataDifference
{
    new T NewMetadata { get; }
    new T OldMetadata { get; }
}

public class MetadataDifference<T> : IMetadataDifference<T>
{
    object IMetadataDifference.NewMetadata { get { return NewMetadata; } }
    object IMetadataDifference.OldMetadata { get { return OldMetadata; } }

    public T NewMetadata { get; private set; }
    public T OldMetadata { get; private set; }
    // Other useful properties

    public MetadataDifference(T newMetadata, T oldMetadata)
    {
        NewMetadata = newMetadata;
        OldMetadata = oldMetadata;
    }
}

public class DifferencesResult
{
    public IEnumerable<IMetadataDifference> MetadataChanges { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either enclosing type must be opened generic:

```
public class DifferencesResult<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<T>> MetadataChanges { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

or you should use methods instead of property:

```
public class DifferencesResult
{
    public IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<T>> GetMetadataChanges<T>();
    private void SetMetadataChanges<T>(IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<T>> value)

    // other fields
}
```

In C#, you can't hold generic property in non-generic class.
It depends on what result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use a closed type, for example:

```
public class DifferencesResult
{
    public IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<string>> MetadataChanges { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

As you cannot have a generic property in a non-generic class.

Comment: I was hoping to be able to have a list which contains different types of objects

Comment: @RaraituL probably `dynamic` is the closest thing then. However I don't think that this is the case to use it.

Comment: or perhaps `IEnumerable<MetaDifference<object>>`

Answer (score 1):

You could either close it:

```
public class DifferencesResult
{
    public IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<{sometype}>> MetadataChanges { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

or use `dynamic`:

```
public class DifferencesResult
{
    public IEnumerable<MetadataDifference<dynamic>> MetadataChanges { get; set; }

    // other fields
}
```

Comment: I think dynamic is expensive when i will box/unbox the value

Comment: It's basically an object that allows anything to be called on it, so if it's a value type you'd have to deal with that, yes.